# Is it okay to ping Google multiple times in a day when my sitemap is updated?

Tags: seo, google, sitemap, xml-sitemap, ping

I have a site where Sitemaps are dynamically generated cos I use an awesome framework.

The framework also has a ping google method.

I'm thinking of pinging Google every time some-one posts something on my Forum.

Is this a good idea cos there might be multiple posts per hour or even per minute if the site grows big.

Also, I might not be able to figure out if the post is new or modification of an existing post.

Is it a good idea to ping Google when a forum post is modified?

Also what about replies?

Comment: I don't know weather should I mark this question as duplicate or not, because title is not similar, but [stephen answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/106184/58259) is perfect for this.

Comment: Ping will work for new topics, but I haven't seen Google recrawl updated pages because you ping them.

Comment: @Goyllo This question is about how often I should ping mainly

Comment: You can ping many times as you want, but when you ping same page multiple time then Google check your page [ETAG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) to understand you've really made any changes or not. If you do that on daily basis, then Google might add your request in queue, because other webmaster don't ping that often, so I think they have some algo which measure priority based on how ping made(api/console) or who(public/owner) made it.