# Google crawler doesn't index multilingual pages

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search-console, googlebot

I need a help with sitemaps and multilingualism. I have a web store the operates on three markets (German, Austrian and Slovenian) and the languages available are English, German and Slovenian.

I would like to explain it through example:

**1)** 10 days ago I sent a sitemap with this structure in GSC:

```
<url>
 <loc>https://example.com</loc>
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com"/>
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com"/>
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-au" href="https://example.com"/>
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="si" href="https://example.com"/>
 <lastmod>2022-01-08</lastmod>
</url>
```

The language in the web shop is determined by the IP address of the visitor, and I expected that my page would magically display sites with Slovenian and German languages to Google crawlers, when necessary.

When I got the results, it was clearly obvious that I made a mistake. For each of the *alternatives*, Google crawler received exactly the same version of the website, in English...

Therefore, only English-language pages were detected.

**2)** When I saw what I did, I corrected the URLs, *lastmod* property, and the way the website determines the language for each user. So, I finally resubmitted the sitemap to GSC.

In this case, when the Google crawler opens, for example, the page https://example.com/de, the website in German language opens, regardless of the IP addres.

```
<url>
 <loc>https://example.com</loc>
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en"/>
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de"/>
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-au" href="https://example.com/de"/>
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="si" href="https://example.com/si"/>
 <lastmod>2022-01-16</lastmod>
</url>
```

However, the GSC now read the sitemap but did not discover any new URLs (for example Slovenian and German language websites).

How can I solve this entanglement the fastest?

Comment: [Google says they don't use the `lastmod` value from sitemaps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105025/sitemap-update-lastmod-and-ping-what-is-the-advantage/106184#106184).  I'm not sure what you are can do here, but updating the `lastmod` won't have any effect.

Comment: Why is `https://example.com/de` tagged with both `de` and `de-au`?  If you have a separate version of the content for German speakers in Austria, you need a separate URL for that too.   (Plus the country code for Austria is `AT`.  `AU` is for Australia.)

Comment: See also [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) which says that it usually takes Google about 2 weeks to react to any changes you make.